# Create typescript type from file name

Tags: typescript

I am using

```
const audioFiles = webpackImportAll(require.context('../assets/audio', false, /\.(mp3)$/))
```

This will import files for me from a folder.

How do i get the type containing the names of those files in
`const fileNames = ['sound1', 'sound2'] as const`
format

Comment: You can't. Is there a reason why you would need to?

Comment: I have a lot of assets that get their name from the filename when they are imported, I would like to customize the tooltips for these names

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by a simple node script that makes not so much:

1. gets names of files from a folder
2. build .ts file with type declaration like this

```html
const cleanIconNames = ['Close','Confirm','Error'] // from previous step
    
fs.writeFile(
 'iconName.ts',
 `export type IconName = ${cleanIconNames.map(t => `'${t}'`).join('|')}`
)

// iconName.ts

export type IconName = 'Close'|'Confirm'|'Error'
```

If you need to generate some complex types you can look at typescript compiler API

Comment: This solution looks like a good starting point! It might help to clarify that this solution would require a _separate_ Node instance to run the script shared above, _before_ doing any further development. It also wouldn't automatically stay up-to-date as the contents of the directory change (you'd need to re-run the script whenever the directory is modified).